# Twitter Widget Covering the page

Tags: css, positioning

The twitter widget on right bottom of sidebar covers the page on some page loads while goes to its right location aftr page refreshes. How can this be corrected.
[check here](http://tinyurl.com/7hq7lz2)

Edit: I guess its a css issue, but not sure.

Comment: hi where is the problem...........

Comment: Can you see the blue widget on right bottom of page? this widget covers the page sometimes when we open the website. Nothing else is displayed then, just the widget.